# Issue with numberOfRowsInSection from Plist file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load data from a plist file and filter it alphabetically and fill the table view with it.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Names", withExtension: "plist")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        nameArray =  try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String]

        alphabetsSection = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

        for letter in alphabetsSection {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF beginswith[c] %@", letter)
            arrayForSection =  nameArray.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
            print(arrayForSection.count)
        }
```

Setup table view :

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return alphabetsSection.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return String(describing: alphabetsSection[section])
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayForSection[section].count
    }
```

App crashes due to `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. I checked and realized that `arrayForSection.count` only works in `for` statement, why ?

Comment: Since the plist file is in the bundle anyway (and won't never change) why don't you save it in the proper format and order?

Comment: `arrayForSection[section]` crashes when `section >= arrayForSection.count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are assigning your filtered array to `arrayForSection` directly. so filtered values of new section will be overwritten on values of previous section.

Rather,

You should do it like keeping a filtered array for each section, in case if there are no filtered values for some letter then empty array will be there for particular section(section refers to alphabet).

**To resolve this:**

Add the filtered results in `arrayForSection` array:

```
    var arrayForSection: [[String]] = []
    for letter in alphabetsSection {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF beginswith[c] %@", letter)
        let filteredResult = nameArray.filter {
            predicate.evaluate(with: $0)
        }
        arrayForSection.append(filteredResult)
    }
```

**To test it, I have taken an array:**

```
    let nameArray =  ["Apple","Cherry","Chips","Mango","Magento","Juice","Strawberry"]
```

and results were:

```
    [["Apple"], [], ["Cherry", "Chips"], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["Juice"], [], [], ["Mango", "Magento"], [], [], [], [], [], ["Strawberry"], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

So for each section you will get an array, either with data or empty. So at `arrayForSection[section].count`, you will not get `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Actually I used  `arrayForSection.append` but no success. Thanks this works now !

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` has a convenience method to group an array of items

```
let dataSource = Dictionary(grouping: nameArray, by: { String($0.prefix(1))})
let alphabetsSection = dataSource.keys.sorted()
```

The corresponding table view datasource and delegate methods are

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return alphabetsSection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return alphabetsSection[section]
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let firstLetter = alphabetsSection[section]
    return dataSource[firstLetter]!.count
}
```